# How to write PHP code to output JSON from directory scan?

Tags: php, json

Need to scan 'Pictures' directory and list all the folder names, number of images in each folder, realpath of any php file in the folder and last modified date of the folder in JSON format. If anyone can help please. JSON format is as under

```
[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Folder1",
      "images":"15",
      "url": "http://website.com/Picturs/file.php", 
      "uploaddate": "08/20/2011" 
    },
    {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Folder2",
      "images":"25",
      "url": "http://website.com/Picturs/file.php", 
      "uploaddate": "08/31/2011" 
    },
    {
      "id":"3",
      "name":"Folder3",
      "images":"13",
      "url": "http://website.com/Picturs/file.php", 
      "uploaddate": "09/20/2011" 
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is get list of directories in Pictures Directory and each directory will have one php file which will have realpath of all the images in that perticular directory.
Trying to get a photo app done for iOS. Where I list albums from this file and the php in each folder will be used to provide data to the UICollectionView.

This is my code so far :

```
<?php
$directoryToScan = "*";

$json_array = array();

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
foreach(glob($directoryToScan, GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $folders) 
{

    //get total number of jpg files in each folder
    $num_files = count(glob("$folders/*.jpg"));


    //find a php file in each folder and get its realpath
    foreach (glob("$folders/*.json") as $filename) {

        //echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
        $phpfile = realpath($filename);
        //echo $phpfile;
    }

    //get date on which each folder was created.
    $fileDate = date("mdY", filectime($folders));   

    $json_Array[] = array('name'=>$folders,'images'=>$num_files,'url'=>$phpfile,'uploaddate'=>$fileDate);

}

echo(json_encode($json_Array));

?>
```

Need to get the "id" which is auto incremented and also the url is not in correct format.
currently it displays like this

```
"http:\/\/www.website.com\/Pictures\/image_001.jpg"
```

instade of `"http://www.website.com/Pictures/image_001.jpg"`

Comment: Where's your code? Are you having trouble with any particular part?

Comment: Give the code on file.php, Explain more what you need to do. what you mean to scan images ?

Comment: I've updated the Question hopefully what i'm trying to do makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working. Thanks to Stackoverflow

```
<?php
$directoryToScan = "*";

define('WEBSITE', "http://www.website.com/pictures/");

$json_array = array();

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
foreach(glob($directoryToScan, GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $folders) 
{
    //get total number of jpg files in each folder
    $num_files = count(glob("$folders/*.jpg"));
    $totalFiles = (string)$num_files;

    //find a php file in each folder and get its realpath
    foreach (glob("$folders/*.json") as $filename) {

        $turl = WEBSITE.$filename;
        $url = str_replace("\/", "\\", $turl);
        //echo($url);
    }

    //get date on which each folder was created.
    $fileDate = date("mdY", filectime($folders));   

    $json_Array[] = array('name'=>$folders,'images'=>$num_files,'url'=>$url,'uploaddate'=>$fileDate);

}

echo(json_encode($json_Array));

?>
```

Posting code just in case if it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Works to me changing the code from Hitz

```
<?php
$directoryToScan = "images/portfolio";

define('WEBSITE', "http://site.com.br/");

$json_array = array();

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
foreach(glob($directoryToScan, GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $folders) 
{
    //get total number of jpg files in each folder
    $num_files = count(glob("$folders/*.jpg"));
    $totalFiles = (string)$num_files;
    //echo $totalFiles;

    foreach (glob("$folders/*.jpg") as $filename) {

        $turl = WEBSITE.$filename;
        $url = str_replace("\/", "\\", $turl);
        //echo($url);

        //get date on which each folder was created.
        $fileDate = date("mdY", filectime($folders));   

        $json_Array[$filename] = array('name'=>$folders,'images'=>$num_files,'url'=>$url,'uploaddate'=>$fileDate);
    }


}

echo(json_encode($json_Array));

?>
```

Output:

```
{
    "images/portfolio/01-grande.jpg": {
        "name": "images/portfolio",
        "images": 16,
        "url": "http:/site.com.br/images/portfolio/01-grande.jpg",
        "uploaddate": "03222019"
    },
    "images/portfolio/01-pequena.jpg": {
        "name": "images/portfolio",
        "images": 16,
        "url": "http:/site.com.br/images/portfolio/01-pequena.jpg",
        "uploaddate": "03222019"
    },
    "images/portfolio/02-grande.jpg": {
        "name": "images/portfolio",
        "images": 16,
        "url": "http:/site.com.br/images/portfolio/02-grande.jpg",
        "uploaddate": "03222019"
    }
}
```