# function fetch_images() from folder not api

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a responsive-image-gallery- code in HTML5 that fetches an image from Filker. I want to fetch image from `img` folder and get the title automatically from the .jpg name this is the code

```
// fetch images from Flickr
function fetch_images() {

    $.getJSON(api_flickr, {
        tags: $("#searchinput").val(),
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            var url = item.media.m;
            var title = item.title;
            var elem = $("<div class='my show'><img src='"+url+"'/><div>"+
                         title+"</div>");
            images.append(elem);
        });
        // add more-div and resize
        images.append($("#morediv").clone().removeAttr("id"));
        resize_images();
    });

}
```

Comment: Your JS code should not change. Show PHP code, read dir contents from using PHP and format same/similar response to your current JS code.

Comment: i have html page not a php code

Comment: i can give you the package if that will helpe i download it from http://tomicloud.com/2014/01/responsive-gallery?demo=1

Comment: How you gonna list all images in dir (if that dir is public accessible)?

Comment: yes its public accessiblte its a html index page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch images from folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46796861/fetch-images-from-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Flicker has an API that provides JavaScript with a JSON-formatted list of filenames.

In order for your script to do the same, you need to either provide it with the same type of API (maybe with a PHP script) or with a list of the filenames in the img folder.

References:

[JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) - Learn what JSON is

[PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523403/how-to-write-php-code-to-output-json-from-directory-scan) - Learn how to create a PHP script to output what you need

Comment: can you help me build it pleas im not a devlopper