# Fetch images from folder

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code that fetches images from Flickr, and I want to change it to fetch images from a folder (without the Flickr API).

I need help. I don't know how to do it.

```html
var api_flickr = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";

// fetch images from Flickr
function fetch_images() {

    $.getJSON(api_flickr, {
        tags: $("#searchinput").val(),
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            var url = item.media.m;
            var title = item.title;
            var elem = $("<div class='my show'><img src='"+url+"'/><div>"+
                         title+"</div>");
            images.append(elem);
        });
        // add more-div and resize
        images.append($("#morediv").clone().removeAttr("id"));
        resize_images();
    });

}
```

Comment: It's not really useful to paste an entire 500 line file into your question. Could you highlight exactly where you are encountering a problem and any error messages you receive etc?

Comment: the devloper of this code send me this :  data source by modifying the code. Just modify function fetch_images(), where you provide a title and url for each image. Local images work too,

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us what you've tried, and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: i want to change the fatchfonction from filkr to own image folder

Comment: I recommend you complete the [tour] to see how the site works, and read [ask] where you'll find tips to improve your questions.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch image from a folder, you may be use ajax/jquery if want javascript.

Here I've done this using PHP. You can test this also.

```
<?php 
$imagesDir = 'images\\';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($images as $key=>$value)
{
  echo "<img src='$value' style='margin:10px'>";
}
?>
```

There is an folder called **`images`**. Then fetch the images using the [php glob function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

> Note : **Code is tested** and working in my site